# Is there a standard way in HTTP to specify no content should be returned?

Tags: http, http-headers, request

For a PUT or POST (for example), I would like to specify to the server that I don't want any content returned in the response, even if it normally would. Essentially I'm looking for a way to perform blind inserts/updates, and was trying to avoid unnecessary response payloads if I have no intention of using them.

I thought maybe `Accept: none` as a request header (or something similar) might be an option, but couldn't find anything to support that.

Is there a standard way to specify this in an HTTP request, or do I have to just live with a little extra content in the response?

Answer (score 0):

I think a minimal response is necessary to know if the request was handled correctly by web servers or if there was errors, even if it has no data other than status code and HTTP headers.

That said, you can use `HEAD` HTTP command to make a GET request having a response without the message body (you get back only headers). But this, AFAIK, doesn't work with POST or PUT requests.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the proposal outlined in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snell-http-prefer-18.